# SQL inner join with max function by groub

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have some problem from using the inner join with group by using max function.
 my detail :
 Table inventory

```
 site_ID  tank_number volume    times-tramp     ID  
  1      1         5000    06/08/2017 15:00      1
  1      1         4900    06/08/2017 15:01      2
  1      2         6000    06/08/2017 15:05      3
  1      3         4000    06/08/2017 15:05      4
  2      1         3000    06/08/2017 15:33      5
  2      2         2000    06/08/2017 15:34      6
  1      1         4800    06/08/2017 15:36      7
  1      2         5800    06/08/2017 16:00      8
```

Table wp_users (wordpress)

```
ID   Name
 1   aaa
 2   bbbb
```

Now, I using with wpdatatable plugin in wordpress so i want use the inner join and group with tank_number and using data update by times-strap
The result should be is :
When user "aaa" login then ID will is 1
the result that want to show.

```
site_ID  tank_number volume    times-tramp       
  1      1           4800    06/08/2017 15:36      
  1      2           5800    06/08/2017 16:00           
  1      3           4000    06/08/2017 15:05
```

But
I got the this result :

```
site_ID  tank_number volume    times-tramp 
1        1           5000    06/08/2017 15:00       
1        2           6000    06/08/2017 15:05       
1        3           4000    06/08/2017 15:05
```

So can every one help to advise me so I have show my code the showing the error due to i can't join with 2 table by correct syntax sql.

this code can work without inner join

```
    select site_id, tank_product, volume, timestramp from inventory as t1
inner join (
    select tank_product as tank, max(timestramp) as time from inventory
    where site_id=1 group by tank_product) as t2
    on t1.tank_product = t2.tank and t1.timestramp = t2.time and t1.site_id=1
```

and Now I trying to using with inner join but not work now.

```
    SELECT inventory.site_id,
       inventory.tank_product,
       inventory.volume,
       inventory.timestramp,
       wp_users.ID
FROM inventory as t1
  INNER JOIN wp_users
  (SELECT inventory.tank_product, max(inventory.timestramp) as time from inventory
   WHERE inventory.site_id=wp_users.ID GROUP BY inventory.tank_product) as t2
     ON t1.inventory.tank_product=t2.tank AND t1.inventory.timestramp=t2.time AND t1.inventory.site_id=wp_users.ID
```

Can advise me for correct way to use the inner join by group by max function.

Answer (score 0):

So, the schema you present and the queries you provided don't line up (naming is all over the place).  It would be very helpful if you provided a sql fiddle to help present your problem (at least in the future).

In any event, I think you were close:

```
select t2.site_id, t2.tank_product, t1.volume, t2.time
from (
select site_id, tank_product, max(timestramp) as time
from inventory 
group by site_id,tank_product) t2
inner join inventory t1
on t2.site_id=t1.site_id and t1.tank_product=t2.tank_product and t2.time=t1.timestramp
inner join wp_users u
on u.id=t2.site_id
where u.id=1
order by t2.site_id,t2.tank_product asc
```

(Assuming you pass the wp_users.id into the query; I've hard-coded that with u.id=1.)

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9992f4/22)

Comment: Thanks you.The result is Ok as i want but it same on the first of my code due to if we fix  the u.ID in the code so it can work but i trying join the user.ID from another table from wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this:

```
SELECT i1.site_ID, i1.tank_product, i1.volume, i.timestramp, iu.User_ID  
  FROM Inventory AS i1
INNER JOIN (
SELECT u.ID AS UserID, i.tank_product, MAX (i.timestramp) AS time
FROM Inventory AS i2 
INNER JOIN wp_users AS u
ON i2.site_id = u.ID
GROUP BY u.ID, i.tank_product  
) as iu
ON i1.tank_product = iu.tank_product 
AND i1.timestramp = iu.time 
AND i1.site_ID = iu.UserID;
```

Comment: I found this error (No results found. Please check if this query is correct! Table Constructor needs a query that returns data to build a wpDataTable.
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as UserID, i.tank_product ) as iu ON i1.tank_product = iu.tank_product AND i1.ti' at line 1)